# How to create a link between two work items programmatically for tfs in javascript?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, tfs-2015

I'm doing some programming for TFS 2015, and I have two work items that I need to add a link between.  I have both work items called, and both of their ids; However, I can't figure out how to add the new link.  Does anyone know how to, or have any helpful resources I can use?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define what type of link to add by using [WorkItemLinkTypeEnd Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.workitemlinktypeend(v=vs.120).aspx), then add the link as related link by using [RelatedLink Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.client.relatedlink(v=vs.120).aspx).

Here is a .net example in [this blog](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2010/02/27/tfs-api-part-22-create-link-between-work-item-parent-child-etc/), you may refer to it:

```
try
{
    LinkTypeItem type = combo_types.SelectedItem as LinkTypeItem;
    int from_wit = Convert.ToInt32(txt_wit_from.Text);
    int to_wit = Convert.ToInt32(txt_wit_to.Text);

    WorkItem from = store.GetWorkItem(from_wit);

    //Define what type of link to add.
    //Child, Parent etc…
    WorkItemLinkTypeEnd linkTypeEnd = store.WorkItemLinkTypes.LinkTypeEnds[type.ReverseEnd.Name];
    //Add the link as related link.
    from.Links.Add(new RelatedLink(linkTypeEnd, to_wit));
    from.Save();

    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Work Item {0}, is {1} of Work Item {2}",
        from_wit, type.ReverseEnd.Name, to_wit),
        "Relation Saved",MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Information);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,"Cannot Save Work Item Relation",MessageBoxButton.OK,
        MessageBoxImage.Error);
}
```

Comment: This would work for 2013 and below, but sadly WorkItemLinkTypeEnd Class and RelatedLink Class aren't available for Visual Studio 2015 so I can't use them.

Comment: These classes are included in assembly Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client, which still can be used in VS 2015.

Comment: Is it usable in Javascript?  I know I can use RestClient by using    `VSS.require(["TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient"]);`

Comment: WorkItemLinkTypeEnd Class and RelatedLink Class provide JScript syntax. As the RestClient documents state, there is no method to create link: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/workitemtracking/restclient/workitemtrackinghttpclient2_1

Comment: The issue I'm having with those classes though is that they are only available up to visual studios 2013, and visual studios 2015 (which I'm using) is not supported for either of those classes.

Comment: If there is a way to use it in visual studios 2015 can you please post some example code on how to do so?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with JScript code, but the classes are included in assembly Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client, have you imported it? I tested in VS 2015, if I include this assembly, these classes are recognized.

Answer (score 0):

"TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient" calls [VSTS Rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/integrate/api/overview) to perform the operations. You can use the [updateWorkItem()](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/workitemtracking/restclient/workitemtrackinghttpclient2_2#method_updateWorkItem) method to add a link to the workitem.

> updateWorkItem()
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> IPromise<Contracts.WorkItem> updateWorkItem(document, id, validateOnly, bypassRules)
> ```

Add the required information in "document" and then call the method. Information can be found here: [Add a link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#add-a-link).